# NameError: name 'capture' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, random-forest

I am working on some code for Face-Recognition. I am trying to combine the csv files that I have into one file that the program will read and once it has an accuracy level of at least 0.8 or higher it will scan my face and determine my expression. When running the program it keeps complaining about the variable "capture". I have tried to change the name but to no avail. I'm not sure what the exact problem is can someone help me in the right direction?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import variable_record
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy

os.chdir("D:\Ezequiel Soler\csv_files/")


def file_combination():
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
    combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    print("Combination is finished")


def create_file():
    print("Prepare for csv files combination...")

    # check whether the combined file is existed
    is_existed = path.exists("combined_csv.csv")

    # ask user whether he/she want to renew the file if the file is already existed
    if is_existed:
        renew = input("The file is already existed, do you renew the file? (Y/N) ")
        if renew.upper() == 'Y':
            os.remove("combined_csv.csv")
            file_combination()
        else:
            print("Program is ended.")
            exit(0)
    else:
        file_combination()
    print("--------------------------------------------")


def main():
    create_file()

    # import dataset
    dataSet = pd.read_csv("combined_csv.csv")

    # preparing data for training
    X = dataSet.iloc[:, 0:7].values
    y = dataSet.iloc[:, 7].values

    # divide data into training data and test data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

    # scaling features
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

    # train the data
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

    # turn on the webcam and check the status
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if capture.isOpened() is False:
        print("Camera Error, please check your camera @_@")
        exit()

    # initial values
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

    while True:
        # change the BGR frame to gray frame
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # use face_recognition library to locate the landmarks
        face_marks = face_recognition.face_landmarks(gray, None, "large")

        if face_marks.__len__() != 0:
            # calculate EAR, MAR, PUC, and MOE
            L_EAR = variable_record.cal_EAR(face_marks[0]["left_eye"])
            R_EAR = variable_record.cal_EAR(face_marks[0]["right_eye"])
            MAR = variable_record.cal_MAR(face_marks[0]["top_lip"], face_marks[0]["bottom_lip"])
            PUC = variable_record.cal_PUC(face_marks[0]["left_eye"])
            EBA = variable_record.cal_EBA(face_marks[0]["right_eyebrow"])
            CAR = variable_record.cal_CAR(face_marks[0]["chin"])
            MOE = MAR / L_EAR

            predict_data = numpy.array([[L_EAR, R_EAR, MAR, PUC, MOE, EBA, CAR]])
            predict_data = sc.transform(predict_data)
            expression = classifier.predict(predict_data)

            # transfer expression value to english
            if expression == 1:
                expression = "Neutral"
            elif expression == 2:
                expression = "Happiness"
            elif expression == 3:
                expression = "Sadness"
            elif expression == 4:
                expression = "Fear"
            elif expression == 5:
                expression = "Angry"
            elif expression == 6:
                expression = "Surprise"
            else:
                expression = "Other"
            print(expression)

            # rectangle the face
            face_point = face_recognition.face_locations(gray)
            for pts in face_point:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (pts[3], pts[0]), (pts[1], pts[2]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                # show the result on the frame
                cv2.putText(frame, expression, (pts[3], pts[0]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.0, (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # press q to exit the loop
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

        # display the frame
        cv2.imshow("Expression Prediction", frame)

    # release the memory
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following piece of code from your main function and place it in the first line after the while loop.

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if capture.isOpened() is False:
        print("Camera Error, please check your camera @_@")
        exit()
```

Comment: Thank You this seemed to work I now have a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The `capture` variable is only defined within the scope of the `main()` function.
In order to call it in your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, you need to return it from the `main()` function.

Comment: Thank You this seemed to work I now have a different error.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is occuring due to this set of codes

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if capture.isOpened() is False:
        print("Camera Error, please check your camera @_@")
        exit()
```

place this after the while code.

Comment: Thank You this seemed to work I now have a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am somewhat new to OpenCV, the code you posted seems to be giving a basic NameError. The error is is somewhat self explanatory, as it pretty much only means that the object you are referencing does not exist.

Looking into your code, it seems like you are using "camera" before defining it, and therefore are confusing the compiler:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if capture.isOpened() is False:
        print("Camera Error, please check your camera @_@")
        exit()
```

I would reccomend putting it under the "while True" loop in main, as it appears it is only avaiable there. You can also try and use [global](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) if you want it to remain in it's current spot.

Answer (score 0):

The error means Civit Ai or where ever the file is located ,
the path has either changes\ has been blocked\ or the server is down\ file has been deleted.